# Automatically remove empty folders in Drive D:

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to develop a batch file to automatically remove empty folders in Drive D like the code below:

```
for /d %%d in (*.*) do (
rmdir %%d
)
```

However, while running the batch file by Windows's job scheduler, I found that the code tried to remove the empty folders into another drive. So how can I change this in coding `(*.*)` to a specific drive D: ?

Comment: Use `for /d %%I in (D:\*) do rmdir "%%I"`. See answer on [Executing BAT files in scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41821620/3074564) for details.

Comment: @matsnow: Oh - good editing! Strange how italicised-`.` and `.` look alike. OP: Use `{}` button to hilight code; Text between  `*`  in narrative *italicises text* Use two `*` instead of one to **bold** text

Comment: Given an empty directory, `D:\c\b\a` this may work, however if `D:\c\b` is also empty it would remain because when it was initially parsed it had content, directory `a`. The only way to be sure you'd cleared all of the empty directories using this idea would be to run the routine multiple times in succession.

Comment: Your code is not checking if the drive is empty before removing it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your script is not executed in drive `D:` when running via scheduled task, but (by default) in the root folder of the user which executes the task.

Add `D:` at the beginning of your batch file:

```
D:
for /d %%d in (*.*) do (
rmdir %%d
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /d %%d in (D:*) do (
```

Note `*` not `.`

if you wish, you can use `d:\directoryname\*` to start the nominated directoryname, or

```
for /d /r "D:\" %%d in (*) do echo %%d
```

to proceed through the directory-tree (note: `ECHO` for safety's sake)

It would be a good idea to use "%%d" for the `RMDIR` because otherwise `directory name containing spaces` will be executed as 'remove the directories "directory" "name" "containing" and "spaces"`'

Comment: `D:*` does not point to the root of the drive, but `D:\*` does; and I'd use `"%%~d"` (although it makes no difference in this situation, but just in general)...

Answer (score 0):

```cmd
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir d:\ /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do 2>nul rmdir "%%~fa"
```

This uses a `dir` command to retrieve the list of all folders under the root of drive `d:`. This list is sorted in reverse order so the child folders appears before its parents. That way if removing a child leaves an empty parent it will also be removed.

This reverse sorted list is processed with a `for /f` command that tries to remove all the folders. As by default `rmdir` does not allow removal of non empty folders, only empty folders are removed.