# Windows batch to keep the newest N files based on the timestamp in filename

Tags: batch-file, timestamp, filenames

I need a batch script to keep only the newest N files based on the timestamp from filename and only if the size is bigger than 150 KB (if the size is less, means the backed up file is damage and can be deleted).
I found similar scripts but only for Linux.

The script should first delete all the files with size less than 150 KB and keep the newest N files using as reference the timestamp from filename not the modified date of the files.

This .txt file is modify a few times per day except the weekend.
The file is backed up a few times per day and the date and time are added in filename.

Example of filename:  `Test_2019-01-16_21-57-34.txt`

Path is: `Z:\`
OS is `Windows 8`

Comment: Break your task up into logical steps, then attempt each step one by one based on web/site searches, and the output of each command used when entered in a command prompt followed by `/?`

Comment: @Compo:I found how to delete the files with size less than a custom size. But I don't know how to filter the files with timestamp in filename.

Comment: Your timestamp is sortable, so if the files all have the prefix `Test_` a `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B /O-N Test_*.txt') do (..)` and checking/counting the files with IFs should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This task could be done with the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
pushd "Z:\" || goto :EOF
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D-H /B /OS "Test_*.txt" 2^>nul') do if %%~zI LEQ 153600 (del "%%I") else goto DeleteOldFiles
:DeleteOldFiles
for /F "skip=5 eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D-H /B /O-N "Test_*.txt" 2^>nul') do del "%%I"
popd
endlocal
```

The directory `Z:\` is set as current directory using command **PUSHD** with exiting batch file execution with `goto :EOF` on failure.

Next command **FOR** executes with `cmd.exe /c` (more precisely `%ComSpec% /c`) in a separate command process in background the command line:

```
dir /A-D-H /B /OS "Test_*.txt" 2>nul
```

The command **DIR** outputs

- the names of non-hidden **files** because of option `/A-D-H` (attribute not directory and not hidden)
- in bare format without any additional data because of option `/B`
- ordered by size with smallest file first and largest file last because of option `/OS`
- matching the wildcard pattern `Test_*.txt` in current directory.

An error message output by **DIR** on not finding any directory entry in current directory matching these criteria is suppressed by redirecting the error message from handle **STDERR** to device **NUL**.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** captures everything written to handle **STDOUT** of started command process and processes the captured output line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself.

**FOR** with option `/F` ignores empty lines which do not occur here on using **DIR** with option `/B`.

**FOR** would split up each line into substrings (tokens) using normal space and horizontal tab as delimiters and would assign just first space/tab delimited string to specified loop variable `I`. This line splitting behavior is disabled by using `delims=` to define an empty list of string delimiters. `delims=` is not really necessary here in this case because of the file names of the backup files do not contain a space character.

**FOR** would also ignore lines on which the first substring after splitting up the line into substrings (not necessarily the substring assigned to the loop variable) starts with a semicolon because of `;` is the default end of line character. A file name can start with a semicolon and so it is better to redefine end of line character with `eol=|` or `eol=?` to vertical bar or question mark which no file name can contain at all. In this case `eol=|` would not be necessary because output by **DIR** are only file names starting with `Test_` and so the default `eol=;` does not need to be overwritten with `eol=|`.

The **IF** command compares si**z**e of current file with value 153600 which is 150 [KiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) and the file is deleted if its size is less or equal this value.

**Note:** Windows command processor uses signed 32-bit arithmetic. So a file with more than 2,147,483,647 bytes (2 [GiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte)) is not correct processed by this **IF** condition. It would be necessary to work around this signed 32-bit arithmetic limitation if backup files can be ever larger than 2 GiB.

Otherwise the first loop is exited with a jump to line below label `DeleteOldFiles` on current file being larger than 150 KiB because this file and all other files output by **DIR** after this file have a file size greater than 150 KiB.

The second **FOR** loop runs again command **DIR** in a separate command process in background. But the **DIR** option `/OS` is replaced by `/O-N` to get the file names output in reverse order according to file name. The file name with newest date is output first by **DIR** and the file name with oldest date in name is output last because of using international date format in the file names.

The second **FOR** command line contains additionally the option `skip=5` to skip first *five* file names, i.e. the *newest five* backup files.

If **DIR** outputs more than *five* file names, all other files being older than the first *five* output file names are deleted by command **DEL** executed unconditionally by second **FOR**.

Finally the initial current directory is set again as current directory using **POPD**.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`

See also:

- [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of `||`.

One more hint: Replace `Z:\` by the [UNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention) path if drive letter `Z:` is assigned to a network resource. And make sure the batch file is executed by an account which has the permissions to access the network resource and delete files in that folder on network resource in case of this batch file is executed as scheduled task. See also [What must be taken into account on executing a batch file as scheduled task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41821620/3074564)

Comment: This is one of the best thought out answers to any question on SO. Thanks for being awesome.