# System cannot find path even though it exists in paths

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, path

Working on a batch file that calls another batch file.

```
K:\Market Risk>call "K:\Market Risk\activate.bat"
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

So I set the path at the beginning of my batch file and made sure it was there:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;K:\Market Risk\

K:\Market Risk>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Shoreline Communications\
ShoreWare Client\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server
\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\
WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\
Shoreline Communications\ShoreWare Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\
Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Shoreline Communications\ShoreWare Client\;
C:\Users\Kyle.Dixon\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Kyle.Dixon\AppData\Local\
Programs\Git\cmd;C:\Users\Kyle.Dixon\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Kyle.Dixon\Documents\
R\R-3.5.2\bin\R.exe;C:\Users\Kyle.Dixon\Documents\R\R-3.5.2\bin;C:\Users\Kyle.Dixon\
AppData\Roaming\MarketView\MarketView ExcelTools\;K:\Market Risk\
```

However, I'm still getting the same error:

```
K:\Market Risk>call "K:\Market Risk\activate.bat"
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Has anyone had this issue before?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) It should help to understand how the environment variable `PATH` is managed by Windows. It is unfortunately not really good managed by Windows which cause lots of problems because of no command is available to safely add/remove a folder path to **system** or **user** `PATH`. The results of missing such a command or executable written by Microsoft to safely update `PATH` with applying all necessary error checks are lots of not good coded scripts which quite often corrupt **system** and **user** `PATH` stored in Windows registry on trying to update them.

My recommendation is opening Windows **Control Panel - System and Security** (on *View by: Category* selected) **- System - Advanced System Settings - Environment Variables** as administrator and cleaning up both `Path` environment variables, the **user** `Path` (upper pane) and the **system** `Path` (lower pane). The window **Environment Variables** can be opened also by clicking on Windows **Start** button, typing on keyboard **environment** and Windows suggests in the menu **Edit environment variables for your account** and **Edit the system environment variables** in the language of Windows. Click on one of the two suggested items and if necessary depending on Windows version next on button **Environment Variables**.

- The **system** `Path` should start always with following default Windows folder paths:

  - %SystemRoot%\System32
  - %SystemRoot%
  - %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
  - %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
  - %SystemRoot%\System32\OpenSSH\

  The **system** `Path` was badly updated once in the past if it does not start anymore with these folder paths exactly as written here. (The last folder path is available only on Windows 10 since version 1809 and of course Windows 11.) `C:\WINDOWS` stored in Windows registry and displayed on editing the **system** `Path` instead of `%SystemRoot%` is an indication that an installer executable or script has not good updated **system** `Path` because of replacing original folder paths with referencing environment variable `SystemRoot` by the expanded version. This does not really matter for these folder paths, but could have been harmful for other folder paths.
- No folder path should exist more than once in one of the two `Path` environment variables.
          Remove all duplicates in **user** `Path` as well as in **system** `Path`.
          Your two `Path` environment variables contain three times:

  - C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
  - C:\Program Files (x86)\Shoreline Communications\ShoreWare Client\
  - C:\WINDOWS
  - C:\WINDOWS\system32
  - C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
  - C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
  - C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

  A folder path existing already in **system** `Path` should not exist a second time in **user** `Path` and of course also not once more in **system** `Path`.
- A folder path can be listed without or with a backlash in `Path`. I prefer folder paths without backslash at end in `Path` as this causes less troubles on updating `Path` in future on using command `reg` by a batch script.

  Environment variable `Path` should contain only **folder paths** and not fully qualified *file names*.
  So `C:\Users\Kyle.Dixon\Documents\R\R-3.5.2\bin\R.exe` is completely nonsense in `Path`.

After cleanup of both `Path` environment variables the folder paths in **system** `Path` should be something like:

- %SystemRoot%\system32
- %SystemRoot%
- %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
- %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
- %SystemRoot%\System32\OpenSSH\
- %CommonProgramFiles(x86)%\Oracle\Java\javapath
- %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn
- %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Shoreline Communications\ShoreWare Client
- C:\Program Files\dotnet

For the last path it is better to keep `C:\Program Files` and do not use `%ProgramFiles%`, except there is `C:\Program Files\dotnet` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet` which I don't know as I don't have such a directory on my Windows computer. For the reason see the Microsoft documentation page [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details).

The **user** `Path` should be finally something like:

- %LocalAppData%\atom\bin
- %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps
- %LocalAppData%\Programs\Git\cmd
- %AppData%\MarketView\MarketView ExcelTools
- %UserProfile%\Documents\R\R-3.5.2\bin

---

There is not much written about environment in which the two batch files are executed. So most written below is pure speculative.

I suppose that drive `K:` is not a drive on a local hard disk, but a network drive. So it is possible that the network resource mapped to drive `K:` is currently not available either because of network resource not mapped to drive letter `K:` or there is network connection issue or a network resource permission issue.

Windows remaps a network resource to a drive letter as once done by the user only on logon of the user because of network drive mappings are user account related stored by Windows in Windows registry. So if the batch file is executed as scheduled task with using a different account or also on user not logged in, the drive `K:` does indeed not exist. The scheduled task executing the batch file must be configured to use the account which has the necessary permissions to access all network resources and local directories/files which are accessed by the batch file. And it is additionally necessary to access files and folders on a network resource with their UNC paths instead of using drive letter `K:` of network drive not existing on execution of the batch file in this environment.

See also: [What must be taken into account on executing a batch file as scheduled task?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41821620/3074564)

But possible is also that the error message

> The system cannot find the path specified.

is not output by `cmd.exe` on processing the batch file containing the command line

```
call "K:\Market Risk\activate.bat"
```

but on a command line executed on processing the batch file `K:\Market Risk\activate.bat`.

Therefore I suggest to remove from both batch files `@echo off` at top or change it to `@echo on` and run the main batch file from within a command prompt window, see [debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564). Then it should be 100% clear which command line in which batch file is responsible for this error message.