# CMD commands not working after executing maven command in command line

Tags: maven, cmd

When i try to run this series of commands

```
cd \ && cd Users/gusenbauerM/IdeaProjects &
cd entities && rd /s /q target && mvn clean install -U && cd ..
```

i get the following error from the last `cd..` command

```
The command "cmd" is either misspelled or could not be found
```

My System Variables look like this:

```
JAVA_HOME    ->     C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot
MAVEN_HOME   ->     C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.4
M2_HOME      ->     C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.4
PATH         ->     %MAVEN_HOME%\bin
```

---

Update

Like [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) pointed out, i don't need the `M2_HOME` variable.

Also, I found out that the error is always displayed after running a Maven command, regardless of which one.

```
mvn -version

Apache Maven 3.8.4 (9b656c72d54e5bacbed989b64718c159fe39b537)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.4
Java version: 11.0.12, vendor: Eclipse Foundation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot
Default locale: de_AT, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
The command "cmd" is either misspelled or could not be found
```

Comment: The variables MAVEN_HOME nor M2_HOME needed. use only `PATH=%PATH%:C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.4\bin` ... The cmd missing means you are calling that programatically...

Comment: "The cmd missing means you are calling that programatically"
Can you explain what you mean by that? @khmarbaise

Comment: After removing `MAVEN_HOME` maven commands are not working @khmarbaise

Comment: The directory separator on Windows is ``\`` and __not__ `/` as on Linux/Mac as explained by Microsoft on documentation page [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). So please use the backslash and not the forward slash in file/folder name strings.

Comment: All the __CD__ commands should be concatenated together and improved to `cd /D "%USERPROFILE%\IdeaProjects\entities"`. `USERPROFILE` is a predefined Windows environment variable as explained, for example, on Wikipedia page about [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows). Open a command prompt window and run `set` to see all environment variables defined by default for your user account. Run `set user` to get just displayed all environment variables defined by default of which name starts case-insensitive with the string `user`.

Comment: Run `set path` in a Windows command prompt window to see the __local__ environment variables `PATHEXT` and `PATH` which the Windows shell defines according to __system__ environment variable `Path` and `PATHEXT` and the __user__ environment variable `Path` if that one exists at all which is not the case by default on Windows. Please take a look on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) It explains in full details the environment variables management on most important `Path`

Comment: See my answer on [System cannot find path even though it exists in paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57442052/3074564) if you need to manually using the Windows GUI the __system__ and/or __user__ environment variable `Path`. Click once on Windows __Start__ button, type on keyboard `environment` and Windows offers two items: __Edit environment variables for your account__ and __Edit the system environment variables__. Click on the latter and make the necessary corrections. Another possibility is running __System Restore__ and restore the entire system before corruption of `Path`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. I did not add `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin` to the `PATH` variable (which replaced the actual one), i created a new `PATH` with variable, which only had the one value `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin`.

So Maven worked but i kinda broke everything else.