# How come running a batch script in task scheduler does not work the same way as running a batch script in file explorer?

Tags: batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

I have a functioning script that works as intended when ran in file explorer, but I am trying to implement a way to run the script on logon. My solution was to use task scheduler, but when I run the script the status says "running," yet, the file doesn't execute.

Here is the following code:

```
@echo on

if exist reboot.txt goto iterate
if not exist reboot.txt goto begin

:begin
echo HOW MANY REBOOTS DO YOU WANT?
set /p input= Enter number: 
type nul > reboot.txt
echo %input% >> reboot.txt
type nul > number.txt
echo 0 >> number.txt
goto iterate

:iterate
for /f " delims==" %%i in (number.txt) do set /A temp_counter= %%i+1 
echo %temp_counter% > number.txt 

for /f "delims=" %%i in (reboot.txt) do set Boot=%%i
echo %Boot%

if %temp_counter% GTR %Boot% (
    echo Numbers match goto end
) else (
    echo Numbers don't match
    start shutdown.exe /r /t 60
    exit
)

:end
del reboot.txt
del number.txt
exit
```

Comment: 1) probably the scheduler starts the bat in the windows directory. Try to add `cd /d %~dp0` at the beginning of the file. 2) the script requires user input - how it is handled through the scheduler?

Comment: Yes, your first solution works! The script only requires user input once when the script is first ran and the scheduler didn't have a problem with that. It was like you said. The scheduler starts in the windows directory, and after adding that line, the bat started executing in task. Thank you very much!

Comment: Take a look at [What must be taken into account on executing a batch file as scheduled task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41821620)